# How to compare Old value with New value in Apex classs, i know to Compare in Apex trigger but i need to Compare in Apex class

Tags: apex

For Example i have field called Number on Custom Page override new button on Object  if i edited that number field and change to new value in need to old value with New value something

EX:old number=123 , New value=1234 how can i compare in apex class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually answered a similar question earlier this morning via IM, and made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/b147b7eca2ff7bb2736635cd3bef4e17) that demonstrates how to detect changes from between when the page loads and the edits a user makes. The main feature is that you need to clone the original object, and then you can compare the differences in your save method.

```
public class UpdateChangedFieldsController {
    SObject oldRecord, currentRecord;
    public UpdateChangedFieldsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        oldRecord = controller.getRecord().clone();
        currentRecord = controller.getRecord();
    }
    public PageReference saveChanges() {
        SObject newClone = currentRecord.getSObjectType().newSObject(currentRecord.Id);
        Map<String, Object> 
            oldValues = oldRecord.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap(),
            newValues = currentRecord.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
        for(String key: newValues.keySet()) {
            if(newValues.get(key) != oldValues.get(key)) {
                newClone.put(key, newValues.get(key));
            }
        }
        try {
            upsert newClone;
            return new ApexPages.StandardController(newClone).view();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please do not consider this offensive, but I'm wondering what benefits are of upserting newClone instead of currentRecord?

Comment: @Oleksiy I take no offense to any question, instead I welcome them. This code primarily demonstrates how a single record could be loaded by two different users, and each could edit separate field values without clobbering each other's edits. Realistically, I'd expect some modification to be required for other purposes, such as the OP, but the concept is similar.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I was using FOR UPDATE in SOQL to make sure users are not overwriting each other' modifications.